# PHP How to prevent foreach from overriding outer variables

Tags: php, foreach, block

Currently I'm trying to clean up as much code as possible of the website of the company I work at, without like completely rewriting (stuff like removing dumb comments like `// declare variables`, clean variable naming, consistency etc.). The code is a huge mess and terrible, uses lots of files which gets included and variables get used between files which makes it really annoying.

The problem is, a simple thing as renaming a variable actually can break a lot. I currently have the following problem:

In file `a` I have a query, looking something like this:

```
$getProductSql = 'QUERY';
$getProduct = $db->prepare($getProductSql);
// some bind values etc.
$getProduct->execute();
$product = $getProduct->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, after that file is included in the index, file `b` will get included which contains the following:

```
$getProductsSql = 'QUERY';
$getProducts = $db->prepare($getProductsSql);
// some bind values etc.
$getProducts->execute();

foreach ($getProducts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $product) {
    // some code
}
```

After that file is included, file `c` will be included which contains the following:

```
if ($product['COLUMN'] === '1')
```

In file `c`, the `$product` variable from file `a` should be used but due to how our structure is and file `b` getting included in between, `$product` from file `a` is replaced with the last value of `$product` from the loop in file `b`.

Is there any way to solve this **without** using 2 different variable names or moving code?

Comment: https://blog.joefallon.net/2015/08/immutable-objects-in-php/

Comment: Where is the $product in file c being defined? If previously it was pulling in from file b then it sounds like it was an existing bug. If not then how was it being assigned and why was it using the same name?

Comment: This is pretty much exactly why you use *functions*, and why functions explicitly scope variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/476.

Comment: Also what is the code in the for loop doing?

Comment: @Jeff The `$product` in file `a` was something before but I changed it because this made more sense. That same old variable was also used in file `c`. (so lets say `$product` was previously `$thecoolproduct`, file `c` used this `$thecoolproduct`. The code in the foreach adds some HTML to certain variables (keep in mind, this isn't my code and the code is a huge mess made by somebody who didn't know what he was doing)

Comment: In that case I would change the foreach loop to have a variable with a more transient name like $p or something similar for now to get it working I'm assuming you plan on refactoring all of it

Comment: I already told the "IT manager" and he said to rewrite it all (which basically has to be done since we're not using a framework and this code is a huge mess which makes it pretty hard to move and refactor) costs too much time, but eventually we'd have to change it since this is terrible. I don't like variable names like `$p` or something but as @deceze said I'll try to solve it with a function first.

Answer (score 1):

As deceze says: there isn't really ... but you could do this:

Leave file a as is.

Change file b like this:

```
$getProductsSql = 'QUERY';
$getProducts = $db->prepare($getProductsSql);
// some bind values etc.
$getProducts->execute();

$p[] = $product;

foreach ($getProducts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $product) {
    // some code
    $p[] = $product
}
$product = $p;
```

And file c like this:

```
if ($product[0]['COLUMN'] === '1')
```

It is a bit confusing and not really nice. And yes, that is why you should rather use a function ...

Alternatively: If you don't need the product array from file b any longer in file c you could also simply do this:

file b:

```
$getProductsSql = 'QUERY';
$getProducts = $db->prepare($getProductsSql);
// some bind values etc.
$getProducts->execute();

$p = $product;

foreach ($getProducts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $product) {
    // some code
}
$product = $p;
```

In that case: no need to change file c

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use functions so I'm gonna look into the code and see if I can make a function around the loop. Else I'll use this method which I'll try to avoid simply due to the fact the extra variable necessary kind of bugs me. Thanks anyways